# Problem in general with 'char*' type - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, formatting, char

I recently created a class for table handling, it is pretty much made of functions for output formatting which are returning a `char*` variable. I created a demo program to check its functionality and solve any kind of issues. Now I'm stuck in a problem. Here's program output:

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐ <-- this series of chars is the top part of the table
│TYPE   │ADDRESS│VALUE  │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│N/A    │N/A    │N/A    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│N/A    │N/A    │N/A    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│N/A    │N/A    │N/A    │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── <-- top part gets veeeeeeery long!
│TYPE   │ADDRESS│VALUE  │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│N/A    │N/A    │N/A    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│N/A    │N/A    │N/A    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│N/A    │N/A    │A      │<-- in this cell is contained a char* variable value. i think this is the
└───────┴───────┴───────┘ problem
```

I have tried redesigning the algorithm of the top part function, but the table has to adapt to its max dimension, so I cannot display the same top part for every table.
Here's the table header and the demo program I used:

```
/* TABLE HEADER */

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NUL '\0'
#else
#define NUL "\0"
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

class basic_table
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> cont_m; //Table content
    int cols_m, rows_m;
    
    int getRecord() //Get the longest string
    {
        int record;
        for (int P = 0, c = 0; P < cont_m.size(); P++)
        {
            while (cont_m[P][c] != NUL) c++;
            record = (record > c ? record : c);
            c = 0;
        }
        return record;
    }
    
    int getLength(int pos) //Localize array position and return string length
    {
        int c = 0;
        while (cont_m[pos][c] != NUL) c++;
        return c;
    }
    
    char* complete(int pos) //Set all string to the same length
    {
        int size = getRecord() - getLength(pos) + 1;
        char* spaces = new char[size];
        for (int P = 0; P < size; P++)
        {
            spaces[P] = ' ';
        }
        spaces[size - 1] = '\0';
        return spaces;
    }
    
    char* bottom() //Bottom part of table formatting
    {
        int size = getRecord() * cols_m + cols_m + 2;
        char* bottom = new char[size];
        bottom[0] = '\300';
        for (int P = 1; P < size - 1; P++)
        {
            for (int R = 1; R <= getRecord(); R++) 
            {
                bottom[P] = '\304';
                P++;
            }
            bottom[P] = (P >= size - 2 ? '\331' : '\301');
        }
        bottom[size - 1] = NUL;
        return bottom;
    }
    
    char* top() //Top part of table formatting
    {
        int size = getRecord() * cols_m + cols_m + 2;
        char* top = new char[size];
        top[0] = '\332';
        for (int P = 1; P < size - 1; P++)
        {
            for (int R = 1; R <= getRecord(); R++) 
            {
                top[P] = '\304';
                P++;
            }
            top[P] = (P >= size - 2 ? '\277' : '\302');
        }
        top[size - 1] = NUL;
        return top;
    }
    
    char* half() //Half part of table formatting
    {
        int size = getRecord() * cols_m + cols_m + 2;
        char* half = new char[size];
        half[0] = '\303';
        for (int P = 1; P < size - 1; P++)
        {
            for (int R = 1; R <= getRecord(); R++) 
            {
                half[P] = '\304';
                P++;
            }
            half[P] = (P >= size - 2 ? '\264' : '\305');
        }
        half[size - 1] = NUL;
        return half;
    }
    
public:
    basic_table(int cols, int rows) : cols_m(cols), rows_m(rows)
    {
        cont_m.resize(cols_m * rows_m); //Set table array size
    }
    
    void fill(int col, int row, std::string text) //Localize array position and set value
    {
        int pos = cols_m * (row - 1) + (col - 1);
        pos = (pos > cols_m * rows_m - 1 ? cols_m * rows_m - 1 : pos < 0 ? 0 : pos); //Protecting against SIGSEGV
        cont_m[pos] = text;
    }
    
    std::string get(int col, int row) //Localize array position and return value
    {
        int pos = cols_m * (row - 1) + (col - 1);
        pos = (pos > cols_m * rows_m - 1 ? cols_m * rows_m - 1 : pos < 0 ? 0 : pos);
        return cont_m[pos];
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, basic_table& object) //Display Table
    {
        stream << std::endl;
        stream << object.top() << std::endl;
        if (object.cols_m * object.rows_m == 1)
        {
            stream << '\263' << object.cont_m[0] << '\263' << std::endl << object.bottom() << std::endl;
            return stream;
        }
        for (int C = 0, c = 1; C < object.cols_m * object.rows_m; C++)
        {
            if (c < object.cols_m)
            {
                if (c == 1) stream << '\263';
                stream << object.cont_m[C] << object.complete(C) << '\263';
                c++;
            } else if (C == object.cols_m * object.rows_m - 1) 
            {
                stream << object.cont_m[C] << object.complete(C) << '\263' << std::endl << object.bottom() << std::endl;
                return stream;
            } else {
                c = 1;
                stream << object.cont_m[C] << object.complete(C) << '\263' << std::endl << object.half() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

typedef basic_table table;

/* DEMO PROGRAM */

//#include "table.h"

int main()
{
    table ptrs(3,4);
    ptrs.fill(1, 1, "TYPE");
    ptrs.fill(2, 1, "ADDRESS");
    ptrs.fill(3, 1, "VALUE");
    ptrs.fill(1, 2, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(2, 2, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(3, 2, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(1, 3, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(2, 3, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(3, 3, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(1, 4, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(2, 4, "N/A");
    ptrs.fill(3, 4, "N/A");
    std::cout << ptrs;
    char* example = new char;
    *example = 'A';
    ptrs.fill(3, 4, example);
    std::cout << ptrs;
}
```

Comment: You’re doing the equivalent of `strlen` on a single `char`…?

Comment: How is this C? C does not have classes.

Comment: You tagged as C language.  The C language doesn't have `class` or `std::vector`.  The conditional compilation at the top is worthless because your code won't compile as C language.  Please edit your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: Look up `std::string::length()` and `std::string::size()`.  You can eliminate a function by using existing functionality.

Comment: I highly recommend splitting the file.  Place the `class` definition and method declarations in a header file.  Place the function definitions (implementations) into a source file.  As is, any source file including your header will have to compile all those functions.  By placing the content into a source file, all those functions will be compiled once.

Comment: Definitely review the [`std::string` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) especially the [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).  There is a constructor that allows you to create a `std::string` of spaces by passing the quantity of spaces.

Comment: Why do you call new to allocate strings ?  std::string does that for you.  As is, your code has gazillions of memory leaks.  You should compute the width of the table ONCE, so all pages are similar.  This should resolve your bug

Comment: Recommend you look at the ncurses library. It is a C library but can be integrated with C++ and it works well with C++. Construct a window *W for each row. Format each row to behave like cells. Each cell will need to be a fixed size (the longest string length) in order to preserve alignment.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I call new because of the user to set table dimension and because i think i must declare first the dynamic `std::string` array to prevent me from making a mistake for not declaring it before

Comment: @LukeLikesPizza   Use std::string, it handles all memory allocations and calls new _and_ delete for you.  In the case of the single char `example` , there is no need to call new at all, declare `example` as a single char and take its address using `&`.   Avoid calling new altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C and C++, thus breaking a basic programming rule:  consistency.

```
 /* TABLE HEADER */

#ifdef __cplusplus  // useless and dangerous definition !!!!
#define NUL '\0'    // NULL is the correct keyword in C++98, defined in stdlib.h
#else               // std::nullptr_t in c++11 onwards, defined in <cstddefs> 
#define NUL "\0"
#endif

// NEVER, EVER define macros before including library headers !!!!!

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

class basic_table
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> cont_m; //Table content
                                     // Your table is only 1-D ???
    int cols_m, rows_m;              // useless repetition of table row count.
                                     // let std::vector handle that
                                     // this avoids bugs.

    // correct data definition. 
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> cont_m;  // 2D table. dimension:[row, column]

   
    int getRecord() //Get the longest string  // NAME is misleading.
    std::vector<size_t> getMaxCellContentsWidths() // renamed to something more appropriate
                                           // and useable result type           
    {
        int record;
        for (int P = 0, c = 0; P < cont_m.size(); P++) // reserve uppercase names for constants !!!! 
        {
            while (cont_m[P][c] != NUL) c++;
            record = (record > c ? record : c);
            c = 0;
        }
        return record;

        // correct code:

        // returns the maximum length of cell column contents, 
        // does not include padding !!!
        std::vector<size_t> result;
        if (cont_m.empty())
            return result;

        // first table row defines table column count  
        const size_t COL_COUNT = cont_m[0].size();
        result.resize(COL_COUNT);

        for (size_t row = 0; row < cont_m.size(); ++row)
        {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < std::min(COL_COUNT, cont_m[row].size()); ++col)
            {
                // this test is needed if you want to print N/A for empty strings
                size_t w = cont_m[row][col].length();
                if (w == 0) w = 3;
                result[col] = std::max(result[col], w);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    // your table is 1-D ???
    int getLength(int pos) //Localize array position and return string length

    size_t getItemLength(size_t row, size_t col) 
    {
        // your code, below is 1980's C style programming for embedded applications
        // with nbo access to the C library.  NEVER do this if you can avoid
        // it. 
        int c = 0;
        while (cont_m[pos][c] != NUL) c++;
        return c;

        // correct code:
        if (row >= cont_m.size() || col >= cont_m[row].size())
            return 0;
        return cont_m[row][col].length();
    }
    
    // this bady named funtion is not needed to print a table.
    // and it's leaking memory.
    char* complete(int pos) //Set all string to the same length
    {
        int size = getRecord() - getLength(pos) + 1;
        char* spaces = new char[size];  
        for (int P = 0; P < size; P++)
        {
            spaces[P] = ' ';
        }
        spaces[size - 1] = '\0';
        return spaces;
        // why don't you return a std::string ???
    }

    /* ... */
};
```

The rest of your code is unfortunately beyond repair, since it assumes storage  for a 1-D table... That is, a table with only one column. Your bug comes from bad original design.  Don't despair, it happens.

Hints for rewrite: do not use raw char pointers, NEVER call new, use the cell contents widths from functions defined above, use C++ constructs, and std library structures and classes.